# Calculation speed by accelerometer

Tags: orientation, physics, accelerometer, gyroscope, sensor-fusion

I trying to calculate speed by accelerometer **LIS331DLH**. 
I am using ZUPT to set to zero velocity.
When i shake acceleromter integration mistake too big.
How to fix this problem?
Maybe to try to detect vibration and ignore measure in this moment?

## Speed graphs:

Move up and down:
[image]

## When shaking:

[image]

integration code:

```
Code:
if (lpMag < 0.25)
{
  vx = 0;vy=0;vz=0;
}
else
{
  vx = vx + potx*samplePeriod;
  vy = vy + poty*samplePeriod;
  vz = vz + potz*samplePeriod;
}
pointXYZ bufV;
bufV.x = vx;bufV.y = vy;bufV.z = vz;
velZUPT.push_back(bufV);
```

potx,poty,potz - accelerometer data

lpMag - magnitude

Comment: Show your integration code

Comment: added to the original post

Comment: Accelerometer measures linear acceleration of sensor + acceleration due to gravity. Unless you filter out acceleration due to gravity, you can't integrate and obtain velocity of sensor.